# calculate joint Probability density function limit distribution of statistics $T_n=(nU_{(1)},nU_{(2)}).$

Tags: probability, self-study

Suppose $U_{(1)} , \dots , U_{(n)}$ is order statistics a random sample from $U(0,1)$.how can find joint Probability density function limit distribution of statistics $T_n=(nU_{(1)},nU_{(2)}).$

Comment: Do you want to know how to find the distribution first (with $n$ as a parameter), but feel perfectly capable of finding the limit as $n \to \infty$ once someone tells you how to find the distribution, or do you know the distribution (for finite $n$) already but are having difficulty finding its limit as $n \to \infty$?

Answer (score 1):

Using [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic#The_joint_distribution_of_the_order_statistics_of_the_uniform_distribution), compute the joint distribution of $(U_{(1)},U_{(n)})$. Transform the density to find the distribution of $(nU_{(1)},nU_{(n)})$. Make $n\to\infty$.